# slideToggle called twice in IE8 only

Tags: jquery

I have a footer which slides up/down when page bottom is reached, the problem is it is called twice in IE8 for some reason.

Can I force it to be called once per page scroll?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           // $('.footer .open').click();
           $('#page-footer').slideToggle();
           console.log('log');
       }
});
```

Comment: Scroll is fired so frequently I would not use slideToggle as there will be browsers that fire more than once. I would explicitly use slideUp or slideDown, based on the scroll value.

Comment: Can you show it as an example?

Comment: `if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= $(document).height()) {` try this.

Comment: I now see you have asked pretty much the same question 4 times so far with different wording so I might as well give up helping you. I strongly suggest you stick to one question for one problem and reword if if circumstances change. As you still have not provided your HTML and styling you are just going to wind up with 4 times as many down-votes. Please stop wasting other people's time :)

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope will help you

```
$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
           // $('.footer .open').click();
           $('#page-footer').slideToggle();
           console.log('log');
       }
});
```

Comment: Always say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Comment: Thanks but it is still firing twice.

Comment: have you checked your console error and also put debugger and check that its firing twice or not.?@BlekStena

Comment: The unbind() method removes event handlers from selected elements.

Comment: i checked in my code its work perfectly in ie8.i think the problem should be other which cause the effect on slidetoggle.

Comment: It does not work. I am using simply the following: `$(window).unbind('scroll').scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       console.log('log');
   }
});` The first time I scroll to the bottom it shows 'log' once, but each time after that it shows it twice instead of once.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because when you slideTogglee the window scrolls again due to the animation. You could add a class to the footer and when you slide you could check if it has that class it shouldnt slideToggle since it already did it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() && !$('#page-footer').hasClass('do-once')) {
       // $('.footer .open').click();
       $('#page-footer').addClass('do-once').slideToggle();
       console.log('log');
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried that, I made it trigger click on the footer which has active class if it is open, but in IE8 the class does not get assigned at all. Also, if I manage to scroll the page in one continuouous motion, it then works normally.

Comment: usind addClass in IE8 seems to not be working, I tried a similar method as well.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? 2+ doesn't support older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

it was tough to emulate the screen scrolling in a JSFiddle (as it is displayed in a frame), but this should show what I meant:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/uhAhZ/2/

Ignoring the hacks to emulate the document and window, you just want to call `slideUp` or `slideDown` based on proximity to the screen edge. Calling them again redundantly does very little, so OK to call on every scroll.

```
$('#content').scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()) {
        $('#page-footer').slideDown();
        console.log('log');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#page-footer').slideUp();
    }
});
```

Note: The `>` may need to be `>=` but I cannot test it properly in a JSFiddle as it needs to be the full browser it for the JSFiddle I hacked it a bit :)

Comment: But shouldn't I put inside $(window).scroll(function() { ?

Comment: Check the Fiddle... it is inside it... I was just showing the changed part! Updated to make it more obvious :) You should get the idea now anyway... *Toggle is bad* in this sort of situation (when you can't guarantee the calls).